How do I group the month together and get a sum total for that month?
My dataframe looks like this
Date        Number
2011-01-13    100
2011-01-22    48
2011-02-08    102
2011-02-28    43
2012-01-17    132
2012-02-21    74
2012-02 24    98
I've dropped the day by using this code-
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df.head()
so my dataframe now looks like
Date        Number
2011-01    100
2011-01    48
2011-02    102
2011-02    43
2012-01    132
2012-02    74
2012-02    98
I want to get the total number for each month but I keep getting error messages and I'm not too sure where I am going wrong.
I've tried
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
Monthly_summary = df.Records_Imported.resample('M', on='Date').sum()
but this brings up "The grouper name date is not found"
I then tried
Monthly_summary = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))
but I then get the "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'" error message.
I am wanting the dataframe to look
2011-01    148
2011-02    145
2012-01    132
2012-02    172

Don't convert your datetime to string, this will work fine
